# пропадает StatusBar после перехода на камеру

Tags: ios, swift

На экране редактирования данных пользователя, можно перейти в камеру, проблема в том что при переходе на камеру пропадает StatusBar во всем проекте. А к примеру если перейти на галлерею то все норм.

Вот скрины в последовательности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как грабли в каждом контроллере:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
return false
```

}

Возможно, ответ найдется здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364/uiimagepickercontroller-breaks-status-bar-appearance?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: спасибо на этом же экране во viewwillappear сделал UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false, все работает. Еще раз спасибо.